# Componentes vuejs en aplicación Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Gente una consulta estoy actualizando una aplicación que desarrolle en laravel 5, básicamente es una aplicacion con varios abm productos, clientes, proveedores, etc, el tema es que estoy actualizando algunas partes con con VueJs, pero tengo algunas dudas de buenas practicas, como por ejemplo que elementos convertir a componentes y que no.
Por ejemplo La pagina donde se encuentra el formulario de alta de cliente, conviene que sea un solo componente vue ?
tengo dudas sobre como dividir las secciones de la aplicación en componentes o si hacer las secciones que sean spa

Me gustaría escuchar sus opiniones

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: como componentes puedes convertir todas las partes interactivas de tu CRUD que se usen de manera repetitiva

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero revisar la sección de [ask], para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Para preguntas dentro de la temática del sitio lee [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Desgraciadamente la pregunta asi como esta es basada en opiniones.. yo por ejemplo trato de componentizar absolutamente todo.

Comment: Exactamente opiniones es lo que busco como para hacer un panorama de la gente que tiene mas experiencia que yo, por eso agradezco todos lo comentarios y experiencias personales que puedan aportar. Saludos.

Comment: te doy un +1 para que puedas acumular mas reputación y entrar al chat donde son mas adecuadas preguntas basadas en opiniones ya que dentro de las publicaciones se espera código y dudas concretas espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: Depende mucho del contenido que tendría el eventual único componente. Si éste a su vez ocupa custom tags, éstos debieran definirse en otro componente. Así mismo, si este único componente tiene un template muy extenso, o muchos métodos o muchos estilos, tendría sentido separarlos. El producto final igual puede terminar siendo una SPA, eso no tiene relación con la estructura que le des a tu o tus componentes